# How to map two variables from SQL Query - MyBatis

Tags: sql, spring, mapping, mybatis

So, I have this select query below, which joins two tables and retrieves a String:

```
<select id =“getAppVerByConfId” parameterType=“java.lang.String” resultType=“java.lang.String”>
SELECT t.app_ver
FROM 
 application a 
   JOIN transaction t on  t.txn_id = a.txn_id
WHERE 
a.confirmation_id = #{0}
</select>
```

and then I used that as a template to write a 2nd query, which is nearly identical, but just retrieves a different parameter from the table.

```
<select id =“getStepNameByConfId” parameterType=“java.lang.String” resultType=“java.lang.String”>
SELECT t.step_name
FROM 
application a 
JOIN transaction t on  t.txn_id = a.txn_id 
WHERE
a.confirmation_id = #{0}
```

Both of these work fine on their own, and they're used at the same point in the program. But there's got to be a better way than this surely? I should be able to make the query once, and then map the results to what I want, correct? Should I make a resultset, and then be able to pull them out? Maybe as a HashMap and I can retrieve the values by keys? Is this a situation where I can USE the AS operator? i.e. "SELECT t.app_ver AS appVersion"? My thinking is that's for passing variables into the query, though, and not for getting them out?

If there's any thoughts on this I would love to hear them. I'm basically trying to combine these into one query, and I need to be able to retrieve the right value and not assign app_ver to step_name or vice versa.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you say it's not a bad idea use alias (`t.app_ver as appVersion`) in your `select` but it is just the name of the column which will be mapped. So in the case you use alias as next `t.app_ver as appVersion, t.step_name as stepName` your column names will be `appVersion` and `stepName`.

Then, to map your result you have multiple choices the idea to map it in a `map` structure is not a bad idea and it's easy, you just need to put your result type as `hashmap`, it will be something like that (and it's not need any `Resultmap`):

#### Hashmap

([Example in offical page](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html))

```
<select id="selectPerson" parameterType="int" resultType="hashmap">
  SELECT * FROM PERSON WHERE ID = #{id}
</select>
```

The column will be the key and the row values the value in the map.

> keyed by column names mapped to row values

So to get your values you will need to use the column name as key in the map:

```
String appVersionValue = map.get("appVersion");
```

#### Resultmap

Other way it to create a class with the properties you need to map and then create your `resultmap`.

A resultmap is defined as next:

> resultMap – The most complicated and powerful element that describes
>   how to load your objects from the database result sets.

Your class would be like:

```
public class Application{

   private String appVersion;
   private String stepName;

   //.... getters and setters

}
```

And your result map would map the column name with the class properties specifying the type with the class created for this (In this case is `Application`):

```
<resultMap id="applicationResultMap" type="Application">
  <result property="appVersion" column="appVersion"/>
  <result property="stepName" column="stepName"/>
</resultMap>
```

(Be careful, because in this example the columns and properties are called equal, there are cases where the column is called app_version and the property appVersion for example so there would be `<result property="appVersion" column="app_version"/>`

Finally in your select you specify to use this `resultmap`:

```
<select id="selectMethodName" resultMap="applicationResultMap">
  select t.app_ver as appVersion, t.step_name as stepName
  from your_table
</select>
```